# How to convert signed to unsigned char in OpenCL?

Tags: c, casting, opencl

I have a signed char in OpenCL that I need to convert to a unsigned char.

Comment: I presume you mean inside an OpenCL kernel

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCL standard defines [explicit conversion functions](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/convert_T.html) for all the built-in scalar and vector types. So you can do something like this:

```
char signed_val = 10;
uchar unsigned_val = convert_uchar(signed_val);
```

Comment: Talonmies: Thanks for informing. Any idea why these conversion functions are needed instead of normal casting?

Comment: @Ashwin: The floating point ones provide explicit control over the various IEEE-754 rounding rules, which casting doesn't. The functions also support all the OpenCL specific vector types, which don't exist in standard C99. Otherwise I think it is for a consistent interface and for better programming practices -- they force the programmer to explicitly choose a conversion behaviour which is always a good thing IMHO.

Comment: Talonmies: If I understand correctly, there is nothing special the conversion functions are doing for char-uchar conversion. In any case, yours is the better answer and I will ask the poster to choose yours.

Answer (score 0):

C-like casting should work. The only difference is that you use cl_ types. But these are equivalent to the C types.

For example, to convert signed to unsigned char:

```
cl_char c   = 0xF;
cl_uchar uc = c;
```

To convert a pointer to signed char to pointer to unsigned char:

```
cl_char* cArr   = // Points to char array
cl_uchar* ucArr = ( cl_uchar* ) cArr; // Access char array as uchar array
```

Comment: All of those `cl_` prefix types are API types for use in host code. I don't think that is what the question is about.